# Make this nice new question the idealized example in the "about" page!

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

This question.

[Playing a Coltrane polychord and the limits of space](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10639/1344)

Isn't that just perfect? Isn't that just great to see a little query, well asked, attractive (pictures are pretty), that just *makes good use of the site to its appropriate purpose.*

So can we vote on it or something? Does it need something done to it? A second answer? A shorter answer?

Comment: Hmm. The existing question on the [about page](http://music.stackexchange.com/about) isn't *bad*. But this one's better.

Comment: That is an excellent question. I don't think I could give an answer anywhere near as good as that existing one, but I can share it with my musical contacts...

Comment: Hey @DrMayhem, welcome to modship!

Comment: Thanks! It's good to be here:-)

Comment: No [fanfare](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/150/1678)? :P Congrats @DrMayhem

Comment: @luserdroog, could you answer this question to take it off the unanswered queue and put a link to it in meta?

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude I've done the first part of your request. I don't understand the second part "link to it in meta" -- **this is meta**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "about" page has been replaced now by the "site tour", so this question/suggestion is somewhat moot.

The example question currently used in the site tour is [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22962/which-fret-do-i-place-a-capo-on-to-play-eb-music-using-c-chords), which is actually pretty perfect for its purpose IMO. The existing question is particularly appropriate when you consider the efforts the community has made to improve it simply as a matter of course.

The polychords question would probably present a more formidable barrier-to-entry.